# Can anyone tell me word by word meaning of Plain Old Java Object in java? also i mostly curious about 'Old' word meaning?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me word by word meaning of "Plain Old Java Object" in java? Also I mostly  curious about 'Old' word meaning?

Comment: Do you know Wikipedia?

Comment: You should be more curious, easy to find a simple definition [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object). For the why is it call like it, this is more a english "saying" (not sure how I can translate what I mean here sorry)

Comment: Neither of those questions answers the OP's question about "old." Look at this question from the POV of a non-native English speaker. It's not unreasonable to ask what the "old" in POJO stands for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's not unreasonable, it's also not a programming question. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/plain-old

Comment: @pvg: Well, I see what you're saying there, but I disagree. You'd basically have to know the answer in order to know it wasn't (by that definition) a programming question.

Comment: @ T.J i know its not programming question but if you know theory part then you will proceed to do it practically.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP don't get the meaning of a word. There is dictionnary for that. I find it difficult to see that as a programming question at all

Comment: @AxelH: Sure, but a dictionary isn't going to tell you what special meaning it has, if any, in the context of Java programming. In any case, reasonable people can disagree, I certainly respect the other view on this, I just don't hold it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well has you said in your answer. It has nothing to do with JAVA. The Plain old has a specific meaning no matter what is behind it. But just like you, I respect your point of view, I just don't agree with it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Old" has no real meaning in that sentence. In American English, a "[plain old](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/plain-old) X" is just a "plain X," an X that isn't special. The "old" is just there for color, nothing more. *(Nice link there from [pvg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087125/pvg).)*

A Plain Old Java Object is a plain Java object, a Java object that isn't special. For more about what a POJO is, see [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object):

> In software engineering, a plain old Java object (POJO) is an ordinary Java object, not bound by any special restriction and not requiring any class path.

Comment: Even if I found the question a bit off-topic, that is not a reason to downvote an answer.